# iOS using image background for Button

Tags: ios5

i have that image background with transparent part and i went using for my buttons without
transparent part and if possible with interface builder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btn setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or you can directly set background image from your xib by changing it into `custom` type.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it you are possibly using the UIButtonTypeRoundedRect style, but UIButtonTypeCustom may be more suitable. You can change this within Interface Builder's inspector window.
still i refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12